# Is it possible to run a swift file in terminal, including a Swift Package?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

Let's say I have a swift package located at `examplefolder/mypackage/` and a swift file `examplefolder/file.swift`. Can I include the package `mypackage` somehow, when I run the swift file with

```
swift examplefolder/file.swift
```

, like I could include it in another package by adding

```
.package(url: "examplefolder/mypackage", .branch("master"))
```

to the Package.swift file?

Comment: Are you wondering if you can use local filesystem packages as dependencies in other local packages, or as dependencies in a single file?

Comment: I want to add dependencies to a single file